# Eclipse find all in one file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse (CDT), is there a way to find all occurrences of a string in a single file?  I can search the entire workspace easily enough using Ctrl-H, and can do "find-next" using Ctrl-F, but I want to be able to see a list of all matches for just one file.

It would be possible to do by setting up a custom file filter for each file I want to search, but that's very clunky.  Eclipse should be able to work out which file I have open and just search that file.

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't find an appropriate option...does it exist?

Comment: Look like Ctrl-F implemented now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and switch to `File Search` as you already mentioned, but set `Scope` to `Selected resources`. Now you can either search the current file, or selected multiple files and search all of them

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out Eclipse can't do this for files opened but not within the workspace (option greyed out), which is tedious.  It works for files in the workspace.

Comment: @Stefan I actually never required that, but tested it right now. It is not greyed out, but says it has an empty scope and does not work...

Comment: Maybe different versions of eclipse?  I'm using Juno Service Release 2

Comment: why can't they add the *"Find All"* button to the `Ctrl`+`F` popup? no nerd folks at Eclipse Foundation thought of something so simple?